# Gearbox doesn’t move when it’s in neutral - Is that normal?

Tags: technic, gears, vehicle, wheel

I’m not sure if the gearbox is supposed to move when it’s in neutral but the gearbox only moves when it’s in drive or rear. If I made an error can someone please tell me if there is a way to fix it?

Comment: I suppose you mean *the cogs **in** the gearbox* should move, right? I mean, I'd be concerned if the gearbox moved, neutral or not ;-).

Comment: Do you just mean the output shaft doesn't turn, or do you mean the input shaft locks up?

Comment: **What gearbox?**

Answer (score 5):

The point of the neutral position in a gearbox is that it disconnects the engine from the drivetrain. Therefore no movement is expected at the wheels when the engine turns and vica versa. If the pistons move (their crankshaft turns) when the wheels are turned in drive and do it backwards when in reverse your build is okay.